# How to calculate resources taken up in quantum computation

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, unitarity

Suppose I have $n$ qubits namely $\{|\psi_{1}\rangle,|\psi_{2}\rangle.....|\psi_{n}\rangle\}$. I apply a series of unitary operations $U_{1},U_{2}...U_{n}$ (applied in order) to these qubits.

Each $U_{i}$ is applied on the joint space of all $n$ qubits, that is on $$\{|\psi_{1}\rangle \otimes|\psi_{2}\rangle \otimes.....\otimes |\psi_{n}\rangle\}.$$
Now I was reading the paper [Quantum Computational Complexity in the Presence of Closed Timelike Curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0309189).

Here they say  repeatedly that some operation on qubits is performed using only polynomial gates (polynomial in the number of input qubits) , so it is done in polynomial time.
But in my case I can say that
   $U=U_{1}U_{2}......U_{n}$
Now only one unitary gate is applied, so only one operation is done, so in constant time the whole operation is done. So how do we calculate time complexity in quantum case. In classical case I know we calculate complexity in terms of number  bit operation (and, or...).

Comment: When you use a quantum system to process information, you're usually using it for just one piece of the algorithm. The paper is saying that you only need a polynomial number of usages of the quantum system. In your language, it's saying that you only need $U$ a number of times which is polynomial in the size of the actual problem being solved.